# Export BigQuery temporary table into multiple files based on value in column

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a following problem.
Basing on query like this:

```sql
SELECT lp_id, MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(lp_id)), 10) AS bucket FROM dataset.table
```

I am doing the query and saving the result as csv in Google Storage.

```golang
// defined in scope:
//   ctx          context.Context
//   bucket       string
//   folderName   string
//   queryString  string

query := bqClient.Query(queryString)
job, err := query.Run(ctx)
conf, err := job.Config()
table := conf.(*bigquery.QueryConfig).Dst

gcsURI := fmt.Sprintf("gs://%s/%s/*.%s", bucket, folderName, "csv")
gcsRef := bigquery.NewGCSReference(gcsURI)
gcsRef.FieldDelimiter = ","

extractor := table.ExtractTo(gcsRef)

// run job...
```

And, what I want to do is to split the result into multiple files basing on the bucket the user is (like users from bucket n into file `{{ n_filename }}`) in one job, to avoid increasing costs for data processing.
Is it possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you have clustering on your table?

Comment: Not in `bucket` dimension. I thought about creating new table and partition it by `bucket`, but I don't think it's possible to do that with temp table (I added a little explanation what's happening before the snippet in the question).

Comment: Yes, I tried to imagine different solutions, I always ended with a minimum of 2 reads of the table volume: 1 full read to create a new one with partition/cluster by bucket + Many read of each partition to create your file (the sum of this read equals the volume of the table). And yes, you can't partition temp tables (they are simply cache result in memory). You need to create a native table, and then to delete it at the end (to not pay storage for nothing).

Comment: I am assuming this will involve multiple buckets? are they all in the same region? Are you tied in to using .csv as an export or could you use avro file for example? Are you splitting your file purely based on cost?